# duplicate row in function of field in talend

Tags: migration, talend, data-migration

> I have the following table A :

- id
- bool_1
- bool_2
- bool_3
- bool_4
- bool_5
- bool_6
- bool_7

> and i have an association table Assoc:

- num_iD (FK of table A, field id)
- name_bool (String)

What i want is, if for the same A.id if one of the bool_X is true create the same number of row in Assoc.

> Exemple :

if i have the following row in A :

- id : 45
- bool_1 : true
- bool_2 : true
- bool_3 : true
- bool_4 : false
- bool_5 : false
- bool_6 : false
- bool_7 : true

I want to have this result in Assoc :

- num_id : 45 , name_bool : "bool_1"
- num_id : 45 , name_bool : "bool_2"
- num_id : 45 , name_bool : "bool_3"
- num_id : 45 , name_bool : "bool_7"

But in my tmap component i don't know how to said that except if a create 7 instance of Assoc and add condition on each field bool_X. But that sound bad...

If someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
try with this
             lookup (assoc)
               |
               |
               v 
your input -->tmap ---> (here you create 7 output groups in tmap)-->tunite and in each group you should have a output filter applied on bool_1==true
for example
output_group_bool1 ---should have condition - bool_1==true
output_group_bool2 ---should have condition - bool_2==true
output_group_bool3 ---should have condition - bool_3==true
...
....
and output of tmap should be merged into tunite or you can write the output of tmap into single file using tfileoutput..
```

Comment: It's what i did but in this case if i have 1000 entry i have to hand write 1000 output group. So there is not an automatic way ?

Comment: then you can write sql to give same output..or a procedure in your DB..with that your trouble of putting this logic in talend will be eliminated..